# Java HashMap computeIfAbsent Illegal Capacity

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap, method-reference

I have a hashMap with an arrayList as its value. I would like to use the computeIfAbsent method to efficiently create the list when a key is not in the map. Then I tried to use `ArrayList::new` instead of `k -> new ArrayList<Integer>()` to make the code more clear, but got "invalid capacity" error if the key is a negative number.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.computeIfAbsent(-4, x -> new ArrayList<Integer>());//This is OK
map.computeIfAbsent(-5, ArrayList::new);//This gives error
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -5
```

Looks like the key is passed to the constructor. Could anyone tell me how this happens? Is it possible I can still use method reference in this case to create the arrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the `computeIfAbsent` method defined:

From the class `java.util.HashMap` source code:

```
@Override
public V computeIfAbsent(K key,Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {

  ... // some code
  V v = mappingFunction.apply(key); // create value
  // ... put value into the map itself
}
```

So we're talking about the `mappingFunction` here: it has to accept one parameter which is in "runtime" is a key (the first parameter to `computeIfAbsent`)

So Java "matches" this Function to the constructor of `ArrayList` that accepts one (int) parameter here, because this is how method inference works, otherwise it won't even compile.

Now, here is a constructor of `java.util.ArrayList` with one int parameter:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        if (initialCapacity > 0) {
            this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
        } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
            this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                               initialCapacity);
        }
    }
```

Since the key is "-5" in your example, this constructor is called with "-5" at the end of the day. It enters the "else" block and hence the exception...

When you use the first construction:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(-4, x -> new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

"x" will resolve to -4 but its ok because you don't pass into the
constructor of ArrayList, or, in other words you don't use it in the mapping function.